# iOS8 and upgrading location authorisation from WhenInUse to Always

Tags: ios, ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have a setting that is shown to the user on first run, and depending on this setting the app will either call requestAlwaysAuthorization or requestWhenInUseAuthorization. If the user said no to this setting and later on changes it to yes, I want the app to try and "upgrade" the location authorisation to Always, but I don't get a popup. Is this possible?